# Хеллоуин

Tags: орфография

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать название этого праздника? Хэллоуин, Хеллоуин или Хеллуин?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словари расходятся, рекомендуют Хэллоуин и Хеллоуин. 
При этом в месте ударения словари также расходятся, втречаются рекомендации ставить его на Э/Е и О.

Вариант "Хеллуин" выглядит совершенно неоправданным как наиболее далёкий от английской фонетики.